# iOS - Change image frame by frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to change an UIImageView's image frame by frame , I have several following image that should be changed by a button . here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {

    for( i = 0; i <= 31; i++ ) {
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic%d.jpeg",i];
               _image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
    }

}
```

the problem is my codes change image to only first frame ,when  I tap the button

Comment: This rolls through **all** the views for each button click. Take out the loop if you want to show the images one by one upon each button click. Write `i = (i + 1) % 31` to increment the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of your value of variable i is always 0

Try this for solution:

Create an instance variable in .h file

```
int imgCount;
```

initialize it in ViewDidLoad method

```
imgCount = 0;
NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic%d.jpeg",imgCount];  // img0 is displayed
_image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];


- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
     //first (by default) img0 is display
     imgCount++;

     if (imgCount > 30) {  //suppose total image is 31 means 0 to 30
         imgCount = 0;
     }
     NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic%d.jpeg",imgCount];
     _image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
}

- (IBAction)previous:(id)sender {
     imgCount--;

     if (imgCount < 0) {  //suppose total image is 31 means 0 to 30
         imgCount = 30;
     }
     NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic%d.jpeg",imgCount];
     _image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
}
```

Comment: thanks , one question , how can do it like this for last frame to first frame ? I know I have to use : `imgCount--;` but this work when next button pressed

Comment: I added that piece of code , but for counting back , code works when next button is pressed

Comment: yes, this works in circular manner means img0, img1, img2 .... img30,img0,img1 ... img30, img0 and so on.  what you want? circular manner moving or something else.

Comment: I mean img 30  , img 29  , img 28 ... img 0

Answer (score 0):

```
// create the view that will execute our animation
     UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

     // load all the frames of our animation
     campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.gif"], nil];

     // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
     campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
     // repeat the annimation forever
     campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
     // start animating
     [campFireView startAnimating];
     // add the animation view to the main window
     [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Also download the source [code form here.](http://appsamuck.com/files/bonfire.zip)